# Get out edges with properties

Tags: networkx

I have a Digraph G with some nodes and some edges:

```py
G.add_edges_from([ ...
('X', 'Y', {'property':  85}), ...
('X', 'T', {'property':  104}), ...
...])
```

However, when I run `G.out_edges('X')`, it returns `OutEdgeDataView([('X', 'Y'), ('X', 'T')])`. Instead, I want to get a list of tuples with the edges (with the **property**), like this:
`[('X', 'Y', {'property':  85}), ('X', 'T', {'property':  104})]`

How should I get these results?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [networkx.DiGraph.out_edges(data=True)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_edges.html).

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([
    ('X', 'Y', {'property':  85}),
    ('X', 'T', {'property':  104}),
    ('Z', 'X', {'property':  104}),
])

print(G.out_edges('X', data=True))
```

```
[('X', 'Y', {'property': 85}), ('X', 'T', {'property': 104})]
```

Comment: I am interest in out edges, not in all edges (edges that go out from X)

Comment: @pentavol Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found no better answer than simply writing a list comprehension like this:

```
def get_out_edges(node, all_edges):
    return [e for e in all_edges if node == e[0]]
```